# Проблема с кодировкой при чтении файла

Tags: php

Есть файл в кодировке ANSI. Открываю файл и вывожу на экран:

```
$data = file_get_contents( $filePath );
echo $data;
```

Но вместо русских букв, вопросительные знаки (�), и кодировка меняется на UTF-8. 
Пробовал конвертировать функцией iconv(), но она удаляет эти символы.
Может сервер неправильно настроен или ещё что нибудь?

Comment: Файл сценария, который это всё дело выводит в какой кодировке?

Comment: файл сценария в UTF-8

Comment: ну вот как я и думал - [кодировки ANSI не бывает](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#Windows_.28ANSI.29_code_pages). так какая у вас именно кодировка ? и что вы пытались скормить iconv ? И ещё вопрос куда вы выводите echo ? на консоль или браузеру ? Если браузеру, то проверьте что кодировка в html установлена та-же что и кодировка вывода.

Comment: выводил в браузер и записывал в файл, результат один. Если я открываю этот файл блокнотом, то всё нормально, а если file_get_contents(), то он искривляется.

Comment: ничего он не искривляется. просто у браузера кодировка utf8 а вы выдаете туда cp1251. **какие параметры iconv вы использовали** ?

Comment: Думаю неправильно использовали iconv.

Comment: iconv('CP1251','UTF-8',$data)

Comment: что будет если 

    $data = iconv('CP1251','UTF-8',file_get_contents( $filePath ));
    echo $data;

Comment: >$data = iconv("CP1251","UTF-8",file_get_contents( $filePath ));
print "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"></head><body>" . $data

>print "</body></html>

Answer (score 1):

отправляйте браузеру ту же кодировку которую имеет файл, отправляйте или через header или через html